# Please give me suggestions to identify scammers from communication data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, data-mining

I have some communication behavior data of carrier subscribers, containing information on calls made, duration and base stations. What do I need to do with this kind of data or what kind of machine learning algorithm can I use to identify the characteristics of fraudsters.

I have a little bit of machine learning foundation, but I don't know how to deal with this kind of data of temporal sequential relationship, but I feel that this sequential relationship is a key factor. For example calling different people successively and moving in different base stations successively. Your ideas and help are very much needed, thanks.

Since my English is not very good, the text is translated using Google Translate, so sorry if anything is not clear.

Comment: I think it is almost impossible to do what you want if you don't have any labels who is a fraudster and who is not. Can a human tell this for a particular subscriber? If not, there is little hope machine learning can help. If yes, you need to collect labels from human experts. Even then the algorithm will just learn to learn human beliefs and not the truth at best.

Comment: Do you have past data on who is a fraudster and who is not ? If not maybe you can start with what you mention. Look at extreme values of different statistics.

Comment: @Valentas Sorry, I forgot to mention the most important point, I have some data of fraudsters (including their communication behavior data) in hand, but the sample size is small, just over 1000. I did feature processing on the communication data and trained using machine learning algorithm, and the result is: logistic regression can reach 80% accuracy. But I think it is not enough.
Thank you very much to both of you.

Comment: @lcrmorin Sorry, I forgot to mention the most important point, I have some data of fraudsters (including their communication behavior data) in hand, but the sample size is small, just over 1000. I did feature processing on the communication data and trained using machine learning algorithm, and the result is: logistic regression can reach 80% accuracy. But I think it is not enough.
Thank you very much to both of you.

Comment: I would start with exploratory analysis and compare various simple parameters (average call duration, number of calls, etc) before trying to build a ML model. accuracy is not a suitable metric in your case and the value of 0.8 does not make sense.

Comment: @Valentas Yes, I have analyzed the underlying data, using features such as average call duration, number of calls, and variance ratio of call numbers to train. 80% of the data is the hit rate in this case. If you don't use accuracy, what do you think would be more appropriate to use?

Comment: @Valentas  I think this dimension is not enough, because call sequence and duration is a very important feature, and if the features are transformed this important information will be lost. I have been trying to understand the LSTM algorithm in the past two days, and from the available information it is suitable for processing sequential data, but it is too difficult to implement.